# Does clang provide method to remove duplicated AST node?

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm working on a project that needs to handle clang AST.

I wonder if there is a method already written that can remove the duplicated AST node??

If not, what is a proper method with efficient of doing so?

Thanks a lot!